# Passing a view to other component from a component

Tags: angular, components

I have been trying to get into Angular (coming from .NET MVC 5). So far I am VERY positive about Angular and I love how it works but I cannot figure out how to solve the following issue that was fairly easy to tackle in .NET Razor.

All my components are, through router-outlet, children of a LayoutModule. This module contains the view with the actual sidebar and top bar (basic bootstrap admin template). What I am trying to achieve is that every child component/page has different sidebar content.

In Razor I could simply define a section in the main template and in every view, using the template containing the section, I could simply type `@section sidebar{ RenderPartial(...) }`.

I have tried to look up stuff about this concept in Angular but I feel like I am running out of terms to google.

TLDR; I am trying to let a component pass a piece of HTML (or a component) to the sidebar of my layout.

Any tips are recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a component for your sidebar and use @Input() property for specific content.

In Parent view :

```
 <app-sidebar [content]="content">
```

In sidebar component :

```
@Input() content : any;
```

And in sidebar view, you have access to specific content send by parent component.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find [multiple named router outlets](https://angular.io/guide/router#add-a-secondary-route) handy. Basically you define a separate component for the main view and for the sidebar in the route configuration.

> A template can also have any number of named outlets. Each named outlet has its own set of routes with their own components. Multiple outlets can be displaying different content, determined by different routes, all at the same time.